# Synchronize office 365 contacts to contacts on my system

Tags: jakarta-ee, synchronize, office365

I have a J2EE system and I use office 365 integrated to my system.

I would like to synchronize contacts on my J2EE system to contacts on office 365.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

as with any SharePoint 2010 environment you're able to communicate with SharePoint thought it's REST interface.

You can access the REST endpoint by using the following URL pattern

http://yoursharepointsiteurl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc

of course you have to do authentication before accessing or writing back to SharePoint data.

You can find [further information on SharePoint's REST interface here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521587.aspx) or [a short summary I wrote on that topic](http://dotnet-forum.de/blogs/thorstenhans/archive/2010/07/14/sharepoint-2010-restful-api.aspx).

There is also the ClientObjectModel but it has some limitations and isn't available for Java.